# Create database in SQL and get an error but everything right

Tags: mysql

I try to install fleetspeak. Use Ubuntu 18.04.
First of all I run this

```
CREATE USER 'fleetspeak-user' IDENTIFIED BY 'fleetspeak-password';
```

Then I want to create database with this

```
CREATE DATABASE 'fleetspeak';
```

But has an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''fleetspeak'' at line 1

Why I can get this?

Comment: Are you executing the scripts one by one? Ensure the first or the second is giving the error.

Comment: Try the create database script without single quotes in dbname

Comment: @Ajith I run this line by line. So error is given by second line.

Comment: @Ajith yes, without quotes it's work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the create database script without single quotes in dbname

```
CREATE DATABASE fleetspeak;
```